# 'Class' not found error in Magento 2 frontend

Tags: magento2, helper

This is a screenshot of the error. 
[image]

My code is

> app/code/Prayag/Module/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template"  name="order_total" template="Prayag_Module::orders.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="order_total_sidebar" template="Prayag_Module::orders.phtml">
    </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="cart_total_sidebar" template="Prayag_Module::cart_view.phtml">
    </block>
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
    </page>
```

> app/code/Prayag/Module/view/frontend/templates/orderes.phtml

```
    <?php

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $customerSession = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
    $customerID = $customerSession->getCustomerId();

    $order = $this->helper('Prayag\Module\Helper\Data')->getCollection($customerID);

    foreach($order as $items){ ?>
    <span>IncrementId :</span><a href="<?php echo $block->getUrl('sales/order/history'); ?>"><?php echo $items->getIncrementId(); ?></a><br>
    <?php
    echo "<b>Subtotal :</b>". $items->getSubtotal(). '<br/>';
    echo "<b>Order Status :</b>". $items->getStatus(). '<br/>';
    echo "<b>Date :</b>". $items->getCreatedAt().'<br/>';

    }
```

> app/code/Prayag/Module/Helper/Data.php

```
    <?php
    namespace Prayag\Module\Helper;
    class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
    {
    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
    $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }
    public function getCollection($customerID)
    {
    $collection = $this->orderFactory->create()->getCollection()->setOrder('entity_id', 'DESC')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customerID);
    $collection->setPageSize(5)->setCurPage(1);
    return $collection;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Post your helper here and the error shows that getLabel function doesn't exist there in heper file

Comment: where should I put that ??

Comment: have you checked `cart_view.phtml` ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems everything is correct in the above code, but the error shows that **getLabel** function from helper is missing and you're calling it somewhere around in home page.

By resolve this just try add

```
public function getLabel(){
}
```

to the helper or run the below commands.

```
rm -rf generated
php bin/magento cac:flu
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, It's help me. Thank you.